# Angular universal resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to force an async call to complete before any of my routes are resolved by extending `route.resolve` like so:

```
var originalWhen = $routeProvider.when;

$routeProvider.when = function(path, route) {
  route.resolve || (route.resolve = {});
  angular.extend(route.resolve, {
    availableCodes: function($rootScope, numbersService) {
      if ($rootScope.isAuthenticated) {
        numbersService.getAvailableCodes().$promise.then(function(data) {
          $rootScope.availableCodes = data.codes;
          console.log('resolve: ' + Date.now());
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return originalWhen.call($routeProvider, path, route);
};
```

What is confusing me is the fact that when I add a `console.log('controller: ' + Date.now())` to my controller the logged time shows that the controller loaded BEFORE my async call in my resolve returned. I was under the impression that my controller would not fire off until after this async call in resolve was indeed resolved. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the shown `when` patch should work as expected.

And it should be

```
    return numbersService.getAvailableCodes().$promise.then(function(data) {
    ...
```

to use this promise as route resolution.